# How to clear other apps cache programmatically in android 11?

Tags: java, android, caching, android-11

I search a lot but can't found any solution. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE I tried with two codes but not working.

this is first one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(ACTION_CLEAR_APP_CACHE);
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CLEAR_APP_CACHE);
```

And this is second one:

```
Intent storageIntent = new Intent();
storageIntent.setAction(ACTION_MANAGE_STORAGE);
startActivity(storageIntent);
```

this is just open only download folder to free some space.

if anyone have solution please post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sachin - this is only delete own application cache. I already write my question title is that I want to delete other applications cache.